# Contents overlapping when using OnboardingSupportFragment

Tags: java, android, androidx, overlap

I'm trying to do an onboarding experience for an app using the `OnboardingSupportFragment` class. All the examples I could find on the internet are doing it with `ViewPager`. When I'm trying to switch the page the contents(title, description, background) remain overlapped from the first page and so on. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The title, description, etc get their value from a Charsequence with the position being the page number that I'm on. It should update automatically. Also, why is nobody using the actual class?
 https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/leanback/app/OnboardingSupportFragment

Answer (score 0):

It appears my problem was due to not setting a background color in onCreateBackgroundView() on the view that is being returned. If you don't set anything the color is black by default but also it's overlapping elements when switching pages. Seems like a bug to me.